# How to copy the elements of 1D int array to MxN Mat in Open CV java?

Tags: opencv, svm, android

I am new to open CV and android. I want to copy the elements of a 1D integer array to a Mat such that the first row of Mat consists of all the elements of the 1D array, the second row of Mat should consist of the next 1D int array and so on. So, if there are 'M' number of 1D int arrays of length 'N', the Mat should be M X N. Can we do this using the .put(int row, int col, int[] data). If so, then how? The open CV documentation on .put is not very clear. http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html

Here is my code,

```
    int[] features;
    Mat trainingData = new Mat();
    features = FindFeatures(mRgba.width(), mRgba.height(), yuv, rgba);
```

After this I need to fill my trainingData from the features Int array such that for 'M' features of length 'N', I get a Mat of M X N. Using this M X N Mat, I will be a able to train the SVM.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you can use the put method: http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#put(int,%20int,%20int[])

And end up with a method looking like this:

```
public void fillMatrinx(Mat matrix, int col, int row, int[][] data)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        int n = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            matrix.put(i,j,data[i][n]);
            n++;
        }

    }
}
```